# Cartesian product with grouping

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0

This is a follow-up to a question I asked yesterday - [Left outer join and group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704425/linq-left-outer-join-and-group-by). I got my requirement slightly wrong in that question.

What I actually need is a Cartesian product of the years and items, with a value produced for each pairing. So, instead of using a left join to get (for example):

```
Year    Name    Value  
1       A       100  
1       B       300  
2       A       150  
2       B       200  
3       (NONE)  0  
4       A       50
```

I need to ensure I have 1 line for each year and item in my 2 lists, with the Value set to 0 if there is no item that corresponds to a given year. The above would then become:

```
Year    Name    Value  
1       A       100  
1       B       300  
2       A       150  
2       B       200  
3       A       0 (data for year 3 is missing for item A, so include a 0 valued row)
3       B       0 (data for year 3 is missing for item B, so include a 0 valued row)  
4       A       50  
4       B       0 (data for year 4 is missing for item B, so include a 0 valued row)
```

I have tried modifying the 2 answers given to the other question but seem to end up with X number of rows per year/item pair, where X is the number of distinct items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any nice way to do it (solely within LINQ).  You could find the distinct names first, get the cartesian product of years and those names, then join your data on that.

p.s., You should change the type of your `Price` field to decimal (which I will assume here) and probably `Quantity` to an integral type.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var altData = myData
    .Select(data => new
    {
        Year = (data.Expiration.Year - now.Year) + 1,
        data.Name,
        Value = Decimal.Multiply(data.Quantity, data.Price),
    });
var names = myData.Select(data => data.Name).Distinct();
var years = Enumerable.Range(1, 20);
var query = from Year in years
            from Name in names
            join data in altData
                on new { Year, Name }
                equals new { data.Year, data.Name }
                into joined
            from data in joined.DefaultIfEmpty(new { Year, Name, Value = 0M })
            select data;
```

Comment: Thanks! Works exactly as required.